# Flexbox - align : center / justify : center with unknown height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to split the page into 4 equal squares with **centered** content. The issue I am having is centering the content due to the .flex-item divs having a viewport height, I am looking for a full flexbox solution, Thank you.

I have tried the following from resources:

justify-content  center

align-items center

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.color_1 {
  background: tomato;
}

.color_2 {
  background: LightGreen;
}

.color_3 {
  background: PowderBlue;
}

.color_4 {
  background: SteelBlue;
}

.flex-item {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
   
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item color_1"><div class="inner"><p>inner</p></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item color_2"><div class="inner"><p>inner</p></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item color_3"><div class="inner"><p>inner</p></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item color_4"><div class="inner"><p>inner</p></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `.flex-item` be flex containers, and use [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to center their content:

```css
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.color_1 {
  background: tomato;
}
.color_2 {
  background: LightGreen;
}
.color_3 {
  background: PowderBlue;
}
.color_4 {
  background: SteelBlue;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item color_1"><div class="inner">inner</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item color_2"><div class="inner">inner</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item color_3"><div class="inner">inner</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item color_4"><div class="inner">inner</div></div>
</div>
```